# Google Maps JS API + JSON - Multiple markers not showing up

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-markers

So, what I need is very simple, I need to put markers in a map, I get the data from a JSON I built using PHP. I looked up all other questions(really) about Google Maps markers not showing up, and none of them worked for me. I can't find the flaw in my code.

The JSON is like this (but 58 items long), 'id' is unimportant:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "lat": "-49.217290",
    "lon": "-16.416160",
    "tit": "Heinz",
    "desc": "18 Machines"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "lat": "-49.235455",
    "lon": "-16.676926",
    "tit": "Warehouse",
    "desc": "10 Machines"
  }
]
```

I'm new here, sorry if I do something wrong. My code is bellow:

```
    <div id="map" class="height-400"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        var myLatLon = {lat: -16.398293, lng: -48.965098};
        var markers = [];

        $.ajax({
            dataType:'json',
            url: "contents/map_data.php",
            success: function(data){
                markers = data;
            }
        });
        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLon,
            zoom: 4,
            //disableDefaultUI: true,
        });

        var i= 0;
        $.each(markers, function(i, item) {
              if(typeof item == 'object') {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.lat),parseFloat(item.lon)),
                map: map,
                    title: item.titulo,
                    label: item.desc
              });
              marker.setMap(map);

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(item.desc);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));
                  i=i+1;
              }
         });
        }                       
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_SECRET_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers variable is an empty array, cause the AJAX request has not returned yet. You should either move your code inside success callback or invoke it from success callback.

Try something like:

```
<div id="map" class="height-400"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        var myLatLon = {lat: -16.398293, lng: -48.965098};
        var markers = [];

        $.ajax({
            dataType:'json',
            url: "contents/map_data.php",
            success: function(data){
                markers = data;
                initMap();
            }
        });
        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLon,
            zoom: 4,
            //disableDefaultUI: true,
        });

        var i= 0;
        $.each(markers, function(i, item) {
              if(typeof item == 'object') {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.lat),parseFloat(item.lon)),
                map: map,
                    title: item.titulo,
                    label: item.desc
              });
              marker.setMap(map);

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(item.desc);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));
                  i=i+1;
              }
         });
        }                       
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_SECRET_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: That acctually worked, now I'm just wrestling with the infowindow, but that is another question, maybe. Thanks man.